# Is there elseIf in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a number of statements

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="xyz== 1">First</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="pqr == 2">Second</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="abc == 3">Third</ng-template>
```

Multiple conditions in above statement can be true.

But what i want is, first check for first statement if true then display and leave the rest

If false, then check for second and so on

how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \*ngIf else in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular-4)

Comment: @Supamiu the question is totally different , Please read the description

i dnt want just if and else

multiple condtions can be true but i want to display the first one which is true and leave the rest

Comment: @Supamiu i need if elseif else, can u suggest if there i any other solution

Comment: Maybe it's more like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812770/angular-4-ngif-else-if then , but there's no `else if` at the moment, mainly because `else if` is less used now, it's either replaced by multiple `if` or a `switch`.

Comment: @Supamiu i checked out this link also but even switch need one condition to be true so that it can define which statement to execute

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch http://plnkr.co/edit/IXmUm2Th5QGIRmTFBtQG?p=preview

Answer (score 16):

You can try using `ngIf` directive like:

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="xyz == 1" [ngIfElse]="second">First</ng-template>
<ng-template #second>
  <ng-template [ngIf]="pqr == 2" [ngIfElse]="third">Second</ng-template>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #third>
  <ng-template [ngIf]="abc == 3">Third</ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

with `ng-container` it will look as follows:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="xyz == 1; else second">First</ng-container>
<ng-template #second>
    <ng-container *ngIf="pqr == 2; else third">Second</ng-container>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #third>
    <ng-container *ngIf="abc == 3">Third</ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

But if you want to use for loop statement i can offer the following solution:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="next; context: { $implicit: 0 }"></ng-container>

<ng-template #next let-i>
  <ng-container *ngIf="conditions[i]">
    <ng-container *ngIf="conditions[i] && conditions[i].condition(); else shift">{{ conditions[i].result }}</ng-container>
      <ng-template #shift >
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="next; context: { $implicit: i + 1 }"></ng-container>
      </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

where `conditions`

```typescript
conditions = [
  {
    condition: () => this.xyz === 1,
    result: 'First'
  },
  {
    condition: () => this.pqr === 2,
    result: 'Second'
  },
  {
    condition: () => this.abc === 3,
    result: 'Third'
  }
];
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pYHsA0pIudZ9z0ma9sGC?p=preview)**

Comment: if i write it manually its fine but can have multiple statements and i populating it with a for loop. writing first , second would be a prob

Comment: maybe i can do "other1" "other2" for now. Is there any other efficient way u can think of?

Comment: I am using Reactive forms in Angular , the problem comes when i have multiple validations and i want to show error message for the first failed validation

Comment: I have those validation's return error strings say firstName.errors.textLength and an array containing error messages to show corresponding to validators

Answer (score 2):

No Currently elseif is not supported

Ngifelse https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do more work in the component:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="status == 'first'">First</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="status == 'second'">Second</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="status == 'third'">Third</ng-template>
```

in component code:

```
status string;
if (xyz == 1)
   status = 'first';
else if (pqr == 2)
   status = 'second';
else if (abc == 3)
   status = 'third';
```

Comment: I am using Reactive forms in Angular , the problem comes when i have multiple validations and i want to show error message for the first failed validation

Comment: I have those validation's return error strings say firstName.errors.textLength and an array containing error messages to show  corresponding to validators

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use *ngIf-then-else and ternary operator:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isFirst; then first; else (isSecond ? second : third)"></ng-container>

<ng-template #first>First</ng-template>
<ng-template #second>Second</ng-template>
<ng-template #third>Third</ng-template>
```