# Angular If statement for 3 cases

Tags: angular

How I can write a switch case or if statement in Angular that works for 3 options,

```
 if Boards.status==1 then "Approved"
 if Boards.status==2 then "Pending"
 if Boards.status==3 then "Rejected"
```

I have tried this but need to add all 3 options.

```
    <td>{{Boards.status==1 ? "Approved": "Pending" }}</td>
```

Comment: You need enclose the second condition in parenthesis: `<td>{{Boards.status==1 ? "Approved": (Boards.status==2?"Pending":"Rejected") }}</td>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this out:

```
<tr [ngSwitch=Boards.status]="switch_expression">
  <td *ngSwitchCase="1">Approved</td>
  <td *ngSwitchCase="2">Pending</td>
  <td *ngSwitchCase="3">Rejected</td>
  <td *ngSwitchDefault>...</td>
</tr>
```

Feel free to refer [link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngif-and-ngswitch/)

Comment: you can use ternary operator too

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with the ternary operator, but there are a couple options.  One is just to replace all the stuff between the interpolation operators with a function that returns the value you want, with the function being just some if/else statements.  The other way would be a bunch of divs or ng-containers that used the ngif/else pattern [*ngIf else if in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812770/ngif-else-if-in-template).

UPDATE:
@Eliseo pointed out you actually can do this with the ternary operator.  From the question you could do it like so I think:

```
<td>{{Boards.status == 1 ? "Approved": Boards.status === 2 ? "Pending": "Rejected" }}</td>
```

The accepted answer also has a good way that I forgot, which is by using `ngSwitchCase`

Comment: NOT, of couse you can use ternary operator, only take care use of parenthesis

Comment: @Eliseo wait yeah you're right, I'll update my answer.